# Cypress with Sauce Labs

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, saucelabs, cypress

In the [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/general-questions-faq.html#How-is-this-different-from-%E2%80%98X%E2%80%99-testing-tool) they states (under the "Sauce Labs" subsection):

> Cypress’s API is written to be completely compatible with Sauce Labs, even though our API is not Selenium based at all. We will be offering better integration with Sauce Labs in the future.

I take this to mean that there is a way to run Cypress tests in Sauce Labs but with some limitations. But I can't find instructions on how to achieve this.

Does anyone know if this is possible yet? And if so... where could I find info on setting it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems SauceLab's support of Cypress is not ready yet:

> We currently don't support Cypress at this time, but it is recommended to upvote the following feature request in our Customer Idea Portal, where our Product team directly reviews input from our customers and prioritizes what will be implemented next based on demand.
>
> https://saucelabs.ideas.aha.io/ideas/SLIDEA-I-286

Comment: FYI Your "This link" is 404.  Last update to the Jira ticket you linked is May 2019 and it is in "Evaluating" status since.  Short answer at this time seems to still be "not ready yet"

Comment: Thanks @harschware - I fixed my answer to remove the broken link.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently an [open beta](https://saucelabs.com/platform/sauce-testrunner-toolkit) for the Sauce Labs Testrunner Toolkit, which is intended to integrate with quite a few popular browser automation tools, including Cypress.  It's in open beta so we can gather feedback and help ensure it meets developers' needs.

The toolkit works as a Docker-based solution for fast setup, and it ships logs and videos up to our cloud so sharing test assets with your team works just like it does for hosted tests.

You can find out more [in the docs](https://opensource.saucelabs.com/testrunner-toolkit/docs/overview.html).